# Swift how do you fit font size to custom frame?

Tags: swift, uibutton, font-size

I have a UIButton with size 50x50. How do I set the font size of the titleLable to be smaller than the size created by adjustFontSizeToFitWidth so the the font size fits in lets say a custom frame like 30x30 while the UIButton's size is 50x50?

```
    let but:UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 80, y: 80, width: 70, height: 50))
    view.addSubview(but)
    but.backgroundColor = .white
    but.titleLabel?.backgroundColor = .green
    but.setTitle("hello", for: .normal)
    but.setTitleColor(.red, for: .normal)
    //this gives the second image, still having the text uncentered.
    //but.contentVerticalAlignment = .fill
    but.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "WarsawGothicSuExt", size: 60)
    but.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
    but.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    but.layoutIfNeeded()
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You add a content inset which defines a margin between the button's bounds and those of its content:

```
button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
button.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
button.layoutIfNeeded()

print(button.bounds)                // (0, 0, 50, 50)
print(button.titleLabel?.bounds)    // (0, 0, 30, 18)
```

You don't need to call `layoutIfNeeded()`. It's included here to make the button update itself immediately so we can get the bounding rects.

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know that. But I ran into another problem. What would you make the initial size of the font? If I make it too small, it will fit well within the button but adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth and the UIEdgeInserts will do nothing to make it fit nicely in the button. On the other hand, if I make the font too big, the height of the titleLable becomes a problem (pushing the text to the bottom and not centering it on the button). I edited my question with sample code and what I got.